# What's the most reliable way of converting a material into reusable code blocks?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

*I'd like to convert certain materials into executable python code without having to re-code them from scratch each time.*

While doing some initial experimentation on the principled shader, I realized that there are a lot of different attribute types and sub-attributes to handle eg. [`ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.input`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.html?highlight=shadernodebsdfprincipled#bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled) collection is holding 23 different structs:

```
<bpy_struct, NodeSocketColor("Base Color") at 0x7fe51de9b0d8>
<bpy_struct, NodeSocketFloatFactor("Subsurface") at 0x7fe51de9b2a8>
<bpy_struct, NodeSocketVector("Subsurface Radius") at 0x7fe51de9b478>
...
```

and calling `dir(ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled)` yields:

> ['**doc**', '**module**', '**slots**', 'bl_description', 'bl_height_default', 'bl_height_max', 'bl_height_min', 'bl_icon', 'bl_idname', 'bl_label', 'bl_rna', 'bl_static_type', 'bl_width_default', 'bl_width_max', 'bl_width_min', 'color', 'dimensions', 'distribution', 'draw_buttons', 'draw_buttons_ext', 'height', 'hide', 'input_template', 'inputs', 'internal_links', 'is_registered_node_type', 'label', 'location', 'mute', 'name', 'output_template', 'outputs', 'parent', 'poll', 'poll_instance', 'rna_type', 'select', 'show_options', 'show_preview', 'show_texture', 'socket_value_update', 'subsurface_method', 'type', 'update', 'use_custom_color', 'width', 'width_hidden']`

**Q:** Is there any clever python trickery using "magic" object attributes or anything in order to store and restore the nodes, their attribute values and *ideally* all node connections as well?

---

If anyone would like to have a material for testing purposes, the following blend contains some kind of production setup *(from [Camera projection without generating UV's?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121210/camera-projection-without-generating-uvs))*.

[image]

Comment: Very nice......

Comment: Perhaps using something like DeepDiff https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/ on each node versus a new node to see non-default values?

Comment: All approaches are welcome @MarkusvonBroady

Comment: If a miracle happens and batFINGER's solution isn't amazing, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady great idea re comparing against new node. Looked at this a while back, there is a q about it too, re nodes not playing the typical blender `bl_rna` game re default settings.  For most props in blender `obj.is_property_set("foo")` returns False if `ob.foo` is default.  Brockers, be a good one to have a blend with sample material to test against.

Comment: Sure @batFINGER. Hopefully a good choice otherwise let me know.

Comment: @brockmann NP from me either, after all this q was written to pay homage to G's answer on another question.  Sad that an undesignated bounty doesn't get distributed to all answers weighted by positive votes.   (Just as I believe there could be more than one _"acceptable"_ answer)  Apologies for not getting back sooner,  took some time away from BSE to regain sanity.  Re https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218377/how-can-i-know-scripts-of-what-i-am-editing-on-mesh#comment368526_218377  check out the answerer's (Films) recent questions and answers... see any patterns?

Comment: Oops, missed that comment yesterday... Agree. However, it is like it is and you absolutely deserve it! Can start another one in a few weeks for Gorgious, I don't mind :) Still hope this nice answers are getting even more attention. No need to apologize, great to have you back though... reassuring that you noticed these patterns too @batFINGER

Comment: I can serialize and deserialize any Blender material configuration in JSON. It is possible for me to save my materials in a FreeCAD file and restore all these materials in Blender from this FreeCAD file. for more information see [this thread on the FreeCAD forum](https://forum.freecad.org/viewtopic.php?p=724595#p724595)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Make a dummy material with each node type of material.**

Following on from the [suggestion in comments by @MarkusvonBroady](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214911/whats-the-most-reliable-way-of-converting-a-material-into-reusable-code-blocks?noredirect=1#comment362670_214911)  couldn't resist....  *Am waiting to see the excellent material serialization answer from you know who,*

Pretty much zip the material node / inputs / outputs etc against a newly added default of same type,  and add to string buffer when not same. Have ignored any read only property and `select`.

**Code and test Run.**

```
import bpy
from math import isclose

LUT = dict()
BLACK = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
WHITE = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
ul = f'#{"-" * 44}\n'
buffer = []


def cmp(v1, v2):
    return (
        (len(v1) == len(v2))
        and all(isclose(*v) for v in zip(v1, v2))
    )


def vformat(nums, n, indent=8):
    nums = [f"{d}" for d in nums]
    return f",\n{' ' * indent}".join([", ".join(nums[i: i + n]) for i in range(0, len(nums), n)])


def fes(collection, prop, data, size, indent):
    output(
        f'{" " * indent}{collection}.foreach_set(\n'
        f'       "{prop}", [\n'
        f'        {vformat(data, size, 8 + indent)}\n'
        f'        ])'
    )


def groups_in_tree(node_tree):
    for node in node_tree.nodes:
        if hasattr(node, "node_tree"):
            yield node.node_tree
            yield from groups_in_tree(node.node_tree)


def group_io(n):
    output(f'node = nodes.new("{n.bl_rna.identifier}")')
    output(f'node.name = "{n.name}"')
    sockets = ("inputs", "outputs") if n.type == 'GROUP_INPUT' else ("outputs", "inputs")
    for skt in getattr(n, sockets[1]):
        if skt.type != 'CUSTOM' and skt.name:
            output(
                f"skt = group.{sockets[0]}.new('{skt.__class__.__name__}', "
                f'"{skt.name}", '
                f')'
            )
            output(f'skt.name = "{skt.name}"')
            dv = skt.default_value
            val = dv[:] if hasattr(dv, "foreach_get") else dv
            output(f"skt.default_value = {val}")
    output()


def colorramp(a, b):
    n = len(a.elements)
    output(f'ramp = node.color_ramp')
    compare(a, b, fstring="ramp.{k} = {va}")
    locs, deflocs = [0.0] * n, [0.0, 1.0]
    cols, defcols = [0.0] * (n << 2), BLACK + WHITE
    a.elements.foreach_get("position", locs), a.elements.foreach_get("color", cols)
    n = n - 2
    if n:
        output(
            f"for i in range({n}):\n"
            f"    ramp.elements.new(0.0)"
        )

    if not cmp(locs, deflocs):
        fes("ramp.elements", "position", locs, 1, 0)

    if not cmp(cols, defcols):
        fes(f'ramp.elements', "color", cols, 4, 0)


def mapping(a, b):
    output(f'map = node.mapping')
    compare(a, b, fstring="map.{k} = {va}")

    for i, c in enumerate(a.curves):
        n = len(c.points)
        pts, default = [0, 0] * n, [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        n -= 2
        if n:
            output(
                f'for i in range({n}):\n'
                f'    map.curves[{i}].points.new(0.0, 1.0)\n'
            )

        c.points.foreach_get("location", pts)
        if not cmp(pts, default):
            fes(f"map.curves[{i}].points", "location", pts, 2, 0)


def output(*args):
    s = " ".join(args) if args else ""
    buffer.append(s)


def compare(a, b, fstring="{k} = {va}", sockets="", i=0, ignore={'select'}):

    props = (
            (k, v)
        for k, v in a.bl_rna.properties.items()
        if (not v.is_readonly or k in ("mapping", "color_ramp"))
        and k not in ignore
    )

    for k, v in props:
        va = getattr(a, k)
        vb = getattr(b, k, None)

        if v.type in ('FLOAT', 'INT'):
            if v.is_array:
                if not isinstance(va, float):
                    va = va[:]
                if vb and not isinstance(vb, float):
                    vb = vb[:]

        if va != vb:
            if v.type == 'ENUM':
                va = f"'{va}'"
            elif v.type == 'STRING':
                va = f'"{va}"'
            elif v.type == 'POINTER':
                if k == "parent":
                    va = f'nodes.get("{va.name}")'
                elif a.type == 'GROUP':
                    return output(f'node.node_tree = groups.get("{a.node_tree.name}")')
                elif issubclass(v.fixed_type.__class__, bpy.types.ID):
                    va = repr(va).replace(f"['{va.name}']", f'.get("{va.name}")')
                elif k == "mapping":
                    return mapping(va, vb)
                elif k.startswith("color_ramp"):
                    return colorramp(va, vb)
            name = f'"{a.name}"' if hasattr(a, "name") else i
            output(fstring.format(**locals()))


def pnode(n, dummy):
    if n.type in ('GROUP_INPUT', 'GROUP_OUTPUT'):
        return group_io(n)
    nodetype = n.bl_rna.identifier
    default = LUT.setdefault(
        nodetype, dummy.nodes.new(nodetype)
    )

    output(f'node = nodes.new("{nodetype}")')
    compare(n, default, fstring="node.{k} = {va}")
    for sockets in ("inputs", "outputs"):
        for i, (a, b) in enumerate(
                zip(
                    getattr(n, sockets),
                    getattr(default, sockets),
                )
        ):

            compare(a, b, fstring='node.{sockets}[{name}].{k} = {va}', i=i, sockets=sockets)
    output()


def material_to_text(m):
    try:
        dummy = bpy.data.node_groups.get("DUMMY")
        if not dummy:
            output("import bpy")
            dummy = bpy.data.node_groups.new("DUMMY", "ShaderNodeTree")
            output("groups = {}  # for node groups")

        if hasattr(m, "use_nodes"):
            # material
            for gn in set(groups_in_tree(m.node_tree)):
                material_to_text(gn)
            nt = m.node_tree
            output(
                f"\n"
                f"{ul}#  Material: {m.name} \n{ul}\n"
                f'mat = bpy.data.materials.new("{m.name}")\n'
                f"mat.use_nodes = True\n"
                f"node_tree = mat.node_tree\n"
                f"nodes = node_tree.nodes\n"
                f"nodes.clear()\n"
                f"links = node_tree.links\n"
            )

        else:
            # group
            nt = m
            output(
                f"\n"
                f"{ul}#  NodeGroup: {m.name} \n{ul}\n"
                f'group = bpy.data.node_groups.new("{m.name}", "{m.bl_rna.identifier}")\n'
                f'groups["{m.name}"] = group\n'
                f"nodes = group.nodes\n"
                f"links = group.links\n"
            )

        for n in sorted(
            nt.nodes,
            key=lambda n: [n.location.x, n.location.y]
        ):
            pnode(n, dummy)
        if nt.links:
            output("#Links\n")
        for l in nt.links:
            output(
                f"links.new(\n"
                f'    nodes["{l.from_node.name}"].outputs["{l.from_socket.name}"],\n'
                f'    nodes["{l.to_node.name}"].inputs["{l.to_socket.name}"]\n    )\n'
            )

    except Exception as e:
        print("There has been an ERROR")
        print(e, e.__traceback__.tb_lineno)
        return False  # failure

    if hasattr(m, "use_nodes"):
        bpy.data.node_groups.remove(dummy)
    return True  # success


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = bpy.context.object.active_material
    material_to_text(m)

    text = bpy.data.texts.new(m.name)
    text.write("\n".join(buffer))
```

Test Run on default "Material" with base color set to Red.  AFAICT Generates the material in test file linked Ok.

```
import bpy
groups = {}  # for node groups

#--------------------------------------------
#  Material: Material 
#--------------------------------------------

mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Material")
mat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = mat.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
nodes.clear()
links = node_tree.links

node = nodes.new("ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled")
node.location = (10.0, 300.0)
node.inputs["Base Color"].default_value = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

node = nodes.new("ShaderNodeOutputMaterial")
node.location = (300.0, 300.0)

#Links

links.new(
    nodes["Principled BSDF"].outputs["BSDF"],
    nodes["Material Output"].inputs["Surface"]
    )
```

**Revision**

*Unlike Madonna and @Gorgeous not so much of a "Material Guy".  TBH I'm a sub-feather-weight when it comes to blenders materials and nodes, so this was a nice little excersize for me.*

Ultimately the idea, as I see it,  is to be able to copy a material via a script in one blend, and re-create it in another.

**Default Values.**

Have kept the verbosity down a bit by not outputting default values. Could turn this off with a flag.  Since non-default values are determined from a newly instanced copy they will be non-default at time of creation. As noted if the defaults change, will need to run script again.

**Node Groups**

Prior handled a  group node by simply pointing the node tree  to its `bpy.data.node_groups` item. Instead this version makes a copy of each node group used in the material. *Was a very easy step, since `nodes` of both is a collection of nodes.* To make sure the new group is used in the generated material by means of  a dictionary `groups`  to associate new with old name

```
groups = {}  # for node groups

#--------------------------------------------
#  NodeGroup: NodeGroup.001 
#--------------------------------------------

group = bpy.data.node_groups.new("NodeGroup.001", "ShaderNodeTree")
groups["NodeGroup.001"] = group
```

could turn this on or off to use existing node groups.

**Curves and Ramps.**

Wired it up to generate mapping and colorramp nodes.  Used `foreach_set` which enables to add an arbitrary point for each extra (over default) and set from a list.

`Color Ramp`

```
node = nodes.new("ShaderNodeValToRGB")
node.location = (-345.2741394042969, 142.6455841064453)
node.parent = nodes.get("Frame")
ramp = node.color_ramp
for i in range(4):
    ramp.elements.new(0.0)
ramp.elements.foreach_set(
       "position", [
        0.0,
        0.25,
        0.45396339893341064,
        0.6530487537384033,
        0.7999999523162842,
        1.0
        ])
ramp.elements.foreach_set(
       "color", [
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.41859403252601624, 0.000635193195194006, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.006493096239864826, 0.21146051585674286, 1.0,
        0.14895662665367126, 0.17292265594005585, 0.2819954454898834, 1.0,
        0.5389295816421509, 0.18324723839759827, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
        ])
```

`RGB Curve`

```
node = nodes.new("ShaderNodeRGBCurve")
node.location = (211.58743286132812, 275.4912414550781)
node.parent = nodes.get("Frame")
map = node.mapping
map.tone = 'FILMLIKE'
map.clip_max_x = 0.8999999761581421
for i in range(5):
    map.curves[0].points.new(0.0, 1.0)

map.curves[0].points.foreach_set(
       "location", [
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.15146341919898987, 0.4256756901741028,
        0.24731720983982086, 0.7837838530540466,
        0.4675609767436981, 0.5506754517555237,
        0.5421952605247498, 0.8445945978164673,
        0.6585365533828735, 0.5608108639717102,
        1.0, 1.0
        ])
for i in range(2):
    map.curves[1].points.new(0.0, 1.0)

map.curves[1].points.foreach_set(
       "location", [
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.3512195348739624, 0.6621621251106262,
        0.5926830172538757, 0.3581080138683319,
        1.0, 1.0
        ])
for i in range(3):
    map.curves[2].points.new(0.0, 1.0)

map.curves[2].points.foreach_set(
       "location", [
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.16463413834571838, 0.581081211566925,
        0.5004880428314209, 0.5777024626731873,
        0.7858536243438721, 0.28378361463546753,
        1.0, 1.0
        ])
for i in range(1):
    map.curves[3].points.new(0.0, 1.0)

map.curves[3].points.foreach_set(
       "location", [
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.6782926321029663, 0.4425675868988037,
        1.0, 1.0
        ])
```

**Frames**

Added  the frames and set as parents to respective nodes, haven't wired up re the location changing, as demonstrated by @Gorgeous.

Comment: Very nice .....

Comment: Nice !! I was scratching my head and found only hacky workarounds, I knew there was a pythonic way to handle it :) Definitely stealing that for the future !

Comment: What happened to `rna_xml` that you you [referred to](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43083/35559) in ancient history? Or would that and/or other lower-level ways of stashing data-blocks. not count for this question?

Comment: @RobinBetts had a better check that moment on re-visiting  that 6yo answer (be a lot less ancient myself if i was 6yo at the time...)  Fortunately OP has phrased the question well --> to create something akin to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65129/how-do-i-create-a-script-for-geometry-i-create  whereas the `rna_xml` , to me, feels more similar to importing / exporting.   (subtle, but different enough?, thoughts)

Comment: I'd rather shovel hunks of bits around, avoiding even  object-description formats, if I knew how.. but I think you're right. @brockmann must have his reasons.

Comment: @batFINGER This evolved in quite the nifty script :)

Comment: Missed this, Thankyou. @Gorgious it _[suffers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230241/what-is-the-best-way-to-encode-a-material-into-python-code)_ from many problems when compared to yours.  Chop, chop add groups to your answer.

Comment: @batFINGER Hmm yes that's insufferable alright ! I'd return the favor though, I think it would be accommodated better on your script, I really like the style, it's like reading a piece of poetry but for computers ^^ I don't understand all of it but I know magic when I see it :p while mine is a hodgepodge Frankenstein monster with mud on its boots

Answer (score 12):

I wrote this script a few months back for a personal project. You can see that it's a lot longer than the other answer :).

It creates statements to set the value of a node input or output, even if it is the same as the default value. I debated it, and despite leading to text files with a very high number of lines in big node trees, I prefer this option. Since the goal of this script is to create a snapshot of the material, and the defaults of today might not be the defaults of tomorrow, or of someone else's custom build, I prefer still writing explicitly all properties.

It could still be changed by the user if they want to, by implementing the proposed solution of python magician @batFINGER for not overwriting default values.

You'll need to learn [how to use a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11604548/7092409).

How to use :

Select your object, select the material you want to copy, run the script. The material code will be added in a new text block.

[image]

```
"""
This scripts "serializes" the active material of the currently selected object
And creates a script readable by the Blender API to recreate said Material.
As any Blender script, it is free to use in any way shape or form.
V 1.1 - 20.10.23
Fixed NodeSocketVirtual error
"""

import bpy

from bpy.types import (
    NodeSocketShader,
    NodeSocketVirtual,
    NodeSocketVector,
    NodeSocketVectorDirection,
    NodeSocketVectorXYZ,
    NodeSocketVectorTranslation,
    NodeSocketVectorEuler,
    NodeSocketColor,

    NodeReroute,

    Object,
    Image,
    ImageUser,
    Text,
    ParticleSystem,
    CurveMapping,
    ColorRamp,

    ShaderNodeTree,
)

from mathutils import Vector, Color


ERROR = "~ ERROR ~"

def get_link_statement(link):
    """
    Build the statement to re-create given link
    """
    return f"""\
links.new({link.from_node.path_from_id()}.outputs[{get_socket_index(link.from_socket)}]\
, {link.to_node.path_from_id()}.inputs[{get_socket_index(link.to_socket)}])\
    """


def value_from_socket(socket):
    """
    Returns the evaluated value of a node socket's default value
    """
    # A Shader socket (green dot) doesn't have a default value :
    if isinstance(socket, (NodeSocketShader, NodeSocketVirtual)):
        return ERROR
    elif isinstance(socket, (
            NodeSocketVector,
            NodeSocketVectorXYZ,
            NodeSocketVectorTranslation,
            NodeSocketVectorEuler,
            NodeSocketVectorDirection)):
        return f"{[socket.default_value[i] for i in range(3)]}"
    elif isinstance(socket, NodeSocketColor):
        return f"{[socket.default_value[i] for i in range(4)]}"
    else:
        return socket.default_value.__str__()


class NodeCreator:
    """
    Helper class to programmatically recreate the passed node
    """
    # These props are internal or read-only
    # and aren't useful in the serialization.
    default_props = (
        "dimensions",
        "draw_buttons",
        "draw_buttons_ext",
        "input_template",
        "inputs",
        "internal_links",
        "isAnimationNode",
        "is_registered_node_type",
        "output_template",
        "outputs",
        "poll",
        "poll_instance",
        "rna_type",
        "socket_value_update",
        "type",
        "update",
        "viewLocation",

        "texture_mapping",
        "color_mapping",

        "filepath",

        "cache_point_density",
        "calc_point_density",
        "calc_point_density_minmax",

        "interface",

        "height",
        "show_options",
        "show_preview",
        "show_texture",
        "width_hidden",
    )

    def __init__(self, node):
        """
        Initialize the node inputs and outputs,
        and the different fields' default values
        """
        self.node = node
        self.input_default_values = []
        self.output_default_values = []
        if not isinstance(node, NodeReroute):
            for _input in node.inputs:
                self.input_default_values.append(value_from_socket(_input))
            for output in node.outputs:
                self.output_default_values.append(value_from_socket(output))

        self.type = type(node).__name__
        self.properties = []  # Could use an ordered dict instead.
        for prop_name in dir(node):
            if prop_name.startswith("_") or prop_name.startswith("bl_"):
                continue
            if prop_name in NodeCreator.default_props:
                continue
            self.properties.append((prop_name, getattr(node, prop_name)))

    def statements(self):
        """
        Build the chain of statements to programmatically recreate the node
        """
        statements = []
        statements.append(f"new_node = nodes.new(type='{self.type}')")
        self.properties = sorted(self.properties, key=lambda p: p[0])
        for prop, value in self.properties:
            if isinstance(value, ImageUser):
                statements.append(f"""\
img_text = new_node.{prop}
img_text.frame_current = {value.frame_current}
img_text.frame_duration = {value.frame_duration}
img_text.frame_offset = {value.frame_offset}
img_text.frame_start = {value.frame_start}
img_text.use_auto_refresh = {value.use_auto_refresh}
img_text.use_cyclic = {value.use_cyclic}
img_text.tile = {value.tile}\
                """)
                continue
            if isinstance(value, ParticleSystem):
                # /!\ Make sure this is executed after node.object statement
                statements.append(f"""\
if new_node.object:
    new_node.{prop} = new_node.object.particle_systems.get('{value.name}')
                """)
                continue
            if isinstance(value, CurveMapping):
                statements.append(f"""\
map = new_node.{prop}
map.clip_max_x = {value.clip_max_x}
map.clip_max_y = {value.clip_max_y}
map.clip_min_x = {value.clip_min_x}
map.clip_min_y = {value.clip_min_y}
map.tone = '{value.tone}'
map.use_clip = {value.use_clip}\
                """)
                # Remove the 2 starting default points and only these :
                for i, curve in enumerate(value.curves):
                    statements.append(f"map_c = map.curves[{i}]")
                    for point in curve.points:
                        statements.append(f"""\
map_c.points.new({point.location[0]}, {point.location[1]})""")
                    statements.append("""\
removed_start = removed_end = False
for i in range(len(map_c.points) - 1, -1, -1):
    p = map_c.points[i]
    if not removed_start and p.location[0] == map.clip_min_x and p.location[1] == map.clip_min_y:
        map_c.points.remove(p)
        removed_start = True
    if not removed_end and p.location[0] == 1 and p.location[1] == 1:
        map_c.points.remove(p)
        removed_end = True\
                    """)
                statements.append(f"map.update()")
                continue
            if isinstance(value, ColorRamp):
                statements.append(f"""\
cr = new_node.{prop}
cr.color_mode = '{value.color_mode}'
cr.hue_interpolation = '{value.hue_interpolation}'
cr.interpolation = '{value.interpolation}'\
                """)
                for stop in value.elements:
                    statements.append(f"""new_stop = cr.elements.new({stop.position})
new_stop.color = {[ch for ch in stop.color]}""")
                # Remove the 2 starting default stops and only these :
                statements.append("""\
removed_black = removed_white = False
for i in range(len(cr.elements) - 1, -1, -1):
    stop = cr.elements[i]
    if not removed_black and stop.position == 0 and all([stop.color[i] == (0, 0, 0, 1)[i] for i in range(4)]):
        cr.elements.remove(stop)
        removed_black = True
    if not removed_white and stop.position == 1 and all([stop.color[i] == (1, 1, 1, 1)[i] for i in range(4)]):
        cr.elements.remove(stop)
        removed_white = True\
                """)
                continue
            if isinstance(value, ShaderNodeTree):
                statements.append(f"""\
ng = bpy.data.node_groups.get('{value.name}')
if not ng:
    new_node.label = \"Missing Node Group : '{value.name}'\"
else:
    new_node.{prop} = ng\
                """)
                continue

            if prop in ("hide", "mute", "use_custom_color"):
                if value:
                    statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = {value}")
            elif prop == "text" and not value:
                continue
            elif prop in ("select", "shrink"):
                if not value:
                    statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = {value}")
            elif isinstance(value, str):
                if value:
                    statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = '{value}'")
            elif isinstance(value, Vector):
                if len(value) == 2:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.{prop} = ({value[0]}, {value[1]})")
                else:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.{prop} = ({value[0]}, {value[1]}, {value[2]})")
            elif isinstance(value, Object):
                statements.append(
                    f"new_node.{prop} = bpy.data.objects.get('{value.name}')")
            elif isinstance(value, Image):
                statements.append(
                    f"new_node.{prop} = bpy.data.images.get('{value.name}')")
            elif isinstance(value, Text):
                if value:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.{prop} = bpy.data.texts.get('{value.name}')")
            elif prop == "parent":
                if value:
                    statements.append(f"""\
parent = nodes.get('{value.name}')
if parent:
    new_node.parent = parent
    while True:
        new_node.location += parent.location
        if parent.parent:
            parent = parent.parent
        else:
            break\
                    """)
            elif isinstance(value, Color):
                statements.append(
                    f"new_node.{prop} = ({value[0]}, {value[1]}, {value[2]})")
            else:
                statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = {value}")
        for i, dv in enumerate(self.input_default_values):
            if dv == ERROR:
                continue
            statements.append(f"new_node.inputs[{i}].default_value = {dv}")

        for i, dv in enumerate(self.output_default_values):
            if dv == ERROR:
                continue
            statements.append(f"new_node.outputs[{i}].default_value = {dv}")

        if not isinstance(self.node, NodeReroute):
            for _input in self.node.inputs:
                if _input.hide:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.inputs[{get_socket_index(_input)}].hide = True")
            for output in self.node.outputs:
                if output.hide:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.outputs[{get_socket_index(output)}].hide = True")
#        DEBUG Print node location as a label :
#        statements.append("new_node.label = str(new_node.location[0]).split('.')[0] + ', ' + str(new_node.location[1]).split('.')[0]")

        return statements


def serialize_material(mat):
    """
    Returns the ordered statements necessary to build the 
    Mateiral generation script
    """
    node_tree = mat.node_tree
    statements = [f"""\
import bpy
new_mat = bpy.data.materials.get('{mat.name}')
if not new_mat:
    new_mat = bpy.data.materials.new('{mat.name}')
    
new_mat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = new_mat.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
nodes.clear()
    
links = node_tree.links
links.clear()
    """]

    statements.append("# Nodes :\n")
    for node in node_tree.nodes:
        for st in NodeCreator(node).statements():
            statements.append(st)
        statements.append("")

    if node_tree.links:
        statements.append("# Links :\n")
        for link in node_tree.links:
            statements.append(get_link_statement(link))

    return statements


def write_material_to_text_block(obj):
    """
    Create or overwrite a text block with the same name as the material
    Which contains all the necessary statements to duplicate the material
    """
    if not obj or obj.type not in ('MESH', 'CURVE', 'VOLUME', 'SURFACE', 'FONT', 'META', 'GPENCIL'):
        return
    am = obj.active_material
    if not am or not am.use_nodes:
        return
    statements = serialize_material(am)

    text_block = bpy.data.texts.get(am.name)
    if text_block:
        text_block.clear()
    else:
        text_block = bpy.data.texts.new(am.name)

    for st in statements:
        text_block.write(st)
        text_block.write("\n")

    return text_block


def get_socket_index(socket):
    return socket.path_from_id().split(".")[-1].split("[")[-1][:-1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_block = write_material_to_text_block(bpy.context.active_object)
```

The code is available there for grabbing
https://github.com/Gorgious56/Material2Script/blob/main/material_to_script.py

Comment: Very nice .....

Comment: Oops, the system has "auto-selected" the answer for the bounty and only assigned half of the rep. I'm sorry, nothing intended, hope you don't mind... sh*t. I'm going to start another one next week.

Comment: @brockmann Haha no problem :) Anyways I think the other answer deserves it more than mine, comparing the two now and my scripts feels really clunky :p

Comment: @Exporer Hello, while I understand your proposed edit of my answer, I think it would have made more sense in a comment. As you noticed my answer is limited in regards to the node group creation. I suggest you look into the other answer of this question, which tackles this gracefully. I created this script for my own use back then, and I didn't need to re-create node group so I never implemented it. Feel free to edit it if you find a better solution. Cheers :)