# Serializing object hierarchies?

Tags: python, blend-files

I realize that what I'm asking for is something that, by nature, converges on a re-implementation of the `.blend` file format (or a GLTF-style exporter that precisely mirrors `.blend`) as it gets closer to full functionality.

I also know we could write our own. Traverse the hierarchy, extend `pickle`, `dill`, `JSONEncoder`, etc. Some good work has also been done recently on [specifically serializing materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214911/whats-the-most-reliable-way-of-converting-a-material-into-reusable-code-blocks), and there's a couple questions about writing exporters, but I haven't found any that (1) aim to work on entire object hierarchies (including geometry data, modifiers, relationships, etc) and (2) fully preserve the data and structure for continued use in Blender.

I wonder whether any other work or tools are already out there.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43017/any-way-of-serializing-blender-cycles-materials-data/43083#43083 can use on any object (very verbose)

Comment: @batFINGER It seems to immediately choke by trying to access custom properties as object attributes: `rna_xml.py", line 222, in rna2xml` `value = getattr(root_rna, attr)` `AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'SomeCustomProperty'`. Hm. Also not sure how to get it to actually save mesh data.

Comment: I can serialize and deserialize any Blender material configuration in JSON. It is possible for me to save my materials in a FreeCAD file and restore all these materials in Blender from this FreeCAD file. for more information see [this thread on the FreeCAD forum](https://forum.freecad.org/viewtopic.php?p=724595#p724595)