# I want to convert my Diffuse Shaders to Principled Shaders

Tags: python, materials, shaders

I just barely imported a scene from an .obj file, but all 83 materials defaulted to Diffuse Shaders of various colors.

To make for a faster workflow, could I use a python script of some sort to convert these shaders to the new Principle Shader?

Comment: See my addon here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79839/31447 (basically the same question)

Comment: @brockmann thought may as well cease the "_deja vu loop_" when Community bumps q.

Comment: @batFINGER Cool, updated the code to make it work with 2.9+