# Change field of a node in a group

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, materials, node-editor

I am trying to make a script that will change the value of a specific node within a specific node group. I have seen from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python) question how to target a node within a material, but I can't see how to change a node within a group.

The target node group exists within several materials, but the materials vary in different scenes, so I don't want to have the script change a specific material unless it has to be that way.

(Note: I know a more common way to solve this would be to use a Driver and Custom Property to change the value of the node, and then have the script change the property. However, I'm running into some issues getting my custom properties to update their drivers reliably, so I'm exploring other options too.)

Comment: Why you can't just use [our nice script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/update-all-materials-but-keep-their-color-and-textures/79839#79839)?

Comment: @brockmann I thought that was for replacing one node with another, not for changing the value of a node within a group? Will have to look again

Comment: It should also properly replace any group, otherwise let me know.

Comment: I don't want to replace the whole group, just change a value node within the group from 0 to 1.

Comment: I don't care. Just thought, duplicating the group, changing the value and replace all the nodes takes 5 seconds to do... @Drudge

Comment: That might work just as well actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly access node group data from

```
node_group = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup']
```

The node group name is the one chosen in the group node

[image: Node group name in group node]

Each node group then has it's own nodes -

```
node_group.nodes
```

You can find a node groups nodes from a material (don't confuse node name with node group name)

```
bpy.data.material['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Group'].node_tree.nodes
```

[image: group node name]

You can get the node group name from the materials group node in `node_tree.name`

```
for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
    if n.type == 'GROUP':
        node_group_name = n.node_tree.name
```

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5430/935) for an example of creating a node group using python.

Once you have the group nodes you can access them the same as normal material nodes.

```
node_group.nodes['Diffuse BSDF'].inputs['Color'].default_value = (1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
```