# How can I convert a scene made in cycles to something I can use in the game engine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine

I have a scene that I created in cycles that I would like to be a place for a camera to be moved around by a keyboard. How would I go along doing this without losing textures and materials?

Do I have to bake it into the file? I'm relatively new to Blender so all help is greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: You have to bake it to textures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Materials from Cycles to Blender Internal Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/convert-materials-from-cycles-to-blender-internal-render)

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/update-all-materials-but-keep-their-color-and-textures