# Use Node Setup for various Materials

Tags: materials, node-editor, color

for a current project I used regular planes and applied a solidify and a bevel modifier on each.

Each of the planes should have another logo on it. So the materials all have the same BSDF - in my case a principled shader - but are all different Materials because of the logos. Also there is a material for the back/side channel of the solidify modifier.

Since I used quite many logos I was wondering if there is a way to change e.g. the roughness for all shaders at the same time.

In other words: Is the a way for objects to share the same Shader but all have their own color input?

Best regards

Janek

Answer (score 1):

You can select the node or the group of nodes you want to share with all objects, then press Ctrl G to group them and rename it (I called it "My Own Node").

So everytime you will edit (pressing Tab) the group, every material will be updated.

In the group you can choose which inputs to show (in my example only color input).

[image]

Comment: In case all materials are set already, you can use [this tiny addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79839/31447) to *replace* the shader nodes with your custom group...