# How do I mass-change the surface of multiple mmd materials to Principal BSDF, but keep the image textures which are located differently?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

How do I mass-change the surface of multiple mmd materials to Principal BSDF, but keep the image textures which are located differently?

Explination: The file was an MMD file imported with an addon. The reason why most solutions don't work is because of the fact that ithe material is an mmd texture. To specify the issue, because of where and how the file was imported, the link of the image texture is shown in a different tab in the material properties named "MMD texture" rather than being located in the "Surface" tab. I want an addon that can change all mmd material surfaces to Principal BSDF, but also change the surface texture to the image texture of the original material. There are about six different objects which has more than 50 different mmd materials assigned to each object.

What I am doing right now is copying the image texture source, changing the surface from "MMDShaderDev" to "Principled BSDF", then change the base color to image texture and paste in the file source.

I am looking for a much faster way of doing this task

[Here's what I currently do to change the material surface](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sE-1sRw3utetX_vGVxLXut7Oi7eH-14u/view?usp=sharing)

I hope I cleared up some confusion

Comment: I think this related question might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/update-all-materials-but-keep-their-color-and-textures?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update all materials, but keep their color and textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/update-all-materials-but-keep-their-color-and-textures)

Comment: While it does look good, the image texture link/file is in a weird place (take a look at the video)