# How to set default values for sliders (node groups)?

Tags: node-editor

I am working on a pretty involved volume shader for artistic looks.

I have created a large node group and because of the way I have things set up small changes in values can change the look drastically, so I want the artist to be able to quickly get back to the original settings for that slider.

Because of this I would like a user to be able to "right" click and choose reset to default values but go to a number I choose for each of my 30 sliders.

However the problem is when I do this it always resets to 0, when I need it to be .75 (for example).

Even when I change it here on the side panel it doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This functionality is present for built-in nodes (that Reset Node button in the Properties shelf). I don't think it's possible so far to define this for custom node groups with built-in tools

Comment: Then do you have any idea what that Default value field is for on the inputs? It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42306/reset-nodes-to-their-default-values

Comment: A dirty workaround is to save the custom node to a different file, then you can append it and it will show as an option in the groups section. Instead of resetting the values, replace the node group.

Comment: What Default value field do you mean?

Comment: The part that is circled on the 1st picture.

Comment: That one isn't default, it's current value of the node property. You can change it either there or on the node itself